# How to set the binary mask in OpenCV python correctly?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image img. I also have a mask with value 255 at all the places where I want to retain the pixel values of img are 0 at all other places.

I want to use these two images viz. the mask and img such that I create a matrix with original img values at places where the mask is 255, and the value -1 at all places where mask is 0.

So, far, I have written this:

```
maskedImg = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
```

but the maskedImg has 0 at all the places where the mask has 0. How can I get the value -1 instead of 0 at all the other places using a fast bitwise operation?

Comment: swap the mask around (bitwise not) and bitwise or it with the image

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for the comment. If I swap the mask and the or the mask with the image, I will have the value 255 at all the places outside the mask. I want the value -1 at all those other places outside the mask.

Comment: not sure why you prefer -1... but OpenCV usually uses uint8 for most of the images, including masks, so probably you have to change the type frist.... for it to be able to have -1

Comment: @Londonguy. 255 *is* -1 to all intents and purposes.

Comment: Also, as @api55 pointed out, you need to indicate the type of your image and tell us what how far you are willing to go in of conversions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is your image's dtype. Default is np.uint8, so you cann't set -1 on the result, it underflows to `-1 + 256 = 255`. That is to say, if the dtype is `np.uint8`, you cann't set it to negative value.

If you want to set to -1, you should change the `dtype`.

```
#masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask).astype(np.int32)
masked = np.int32(img)
masked[mask==0] = -1
```